# Sorting By Year

Tags: excel

I have about 10k files in folders and sub folders. I already used "dir /s /b > print.txt" and pasted them into an excel file.

The problem is I have to sort them by year, but the year is in MM-DD-YYYY format at the end of the file name. Is there a way to sort these by year?

Comment: Use a helper column that contains only the date.

Comment: "... sort them by year" - what about the rest of the date?  Would Dec, 2019 come before Jan, 2019?  Probably not.  Why not just **sort by date**?  Can you [edit] in what some of your cells look like, and anything you've tried so far that didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,4)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Then sort cols **A** & **B** by **B**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=Year()` worksheet function for that: it calculates the year number of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier if you put up a sample piece of data but assuming the filename/date cell looks something like =filename_03-27-2020 and you want to extract just the last four digits as the year....
if filename_03-27_2020 is in cell A1 use the formula =RIGHT(A1,4) in cell B1.  The result will be 2020.  Give each column heading names and either sort the range or use a pivot table.